# showing and hiding something on slide toggle in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a panel having slide toggle effect on click of a button along with this slide toggle i am also hiding one div on the click event what i want when the panel slide down that div should hide and when panel slide up the div reappear how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use callbacks and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), say your `<div>`s looked like this for illsutration:

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<div id="one">Hi! I'm div #one, how ya doin?</div>
<div id="two">I show only when one is gone</div>
```

You could do this:

```
​$("button").toggle(function() {
    $("#two").hide();
    $("#one").slideDown();
}, function() {
    $("#one").slideUp(function() {
       $("#two").show(); 
    });
});​​​
```

[You can give that a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tCNjS/), or you could change them out if they're meant to occupy the same area by [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) on *both*, like this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#one, #two").slideToggle();
});​
```

[You can give that a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tCNjS/1/).